# Using SQL Mode in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: sql, arcgis-pro

I am trying to build a SQL expression using SQL Mode in "Make Feature Layer" tool. I have a Land Use/Land Cover Layer that contains several residential classifications (low density, medium density, high density, rural). I want to build a SQL statement that makes the Feature Layer out of any feature that has the word "RESIDENTIAL" in their label. I can't seem to get the logic right.

I thought it was going to be like ArcMap where they have the "SELECT * FROM WHERE" already implied, but that doesn't seem to be the case. 
I tried "RESIDENTIAL" IN LABEL12, like how I would in ArcMap, but that didn't work either.

My statement is as follows: 
          SELECT * FROM "Land Use 2012" WHERE LABEL12 LIKE "RESIDENTIAL"

Comment: Table names do not permit spaces -- `"Land Use 2012"` won't work.  What is the name of the base table (not layer)?

Comment: @Vince Good point! It is "LandUse12."

Comment: MakeFeatureLayer only allows the where_clause and you also need a wild-card with the Like operator, so try Label12 like '%RESIDENTAIL%'. I don't know if the wild-cards differ between Shapefile and fgdb.